# Annual Self Classification Report - Do I need to?

Tags: ios, app-store, app-store-connect

My iOS App ONLY makes HTTPS calls to send data from the app to the server. And I also use bcrypt to encrypt passwords on the back end. Would I need to submit a classification report? This is what I see when I click 'No' when asked to provide export compliance information.

[image]

And this is what I see when I click 'Yes' and 'Next'
[image]

I am located in Asia, so which options should I check? And would I need to submit a self classification report if my app only makes HTTPS calls to send data to the server and only uses encryption in the back end?

Answer (score 1):

As of March 2021 it's no longer needed it's no longer needed if you only use HTTPS.

The same link David has posted has been updated:

> Starting on March 29th, 2021 apps using only exempt encryption no
> longer require you to submit an annual self-classification report.
> Please consult a lawyer if your app uses non-exempt encryption because
> the remainder of this article assumes your app only uses exempt
> encryption.

https://getonthestore.com/export-compliance/

They refer this file:
https://www.bis.doc.gov/index.php/documents/pdfs/2759-table-of-changes-to-enc-in-wa2019-rule-final-version/file

Answer (score 0):

The connection between your app and your server is encrypted when you make HTTPS calls so your app is using encryption.

Your app is subject to Export Administration Regulations when you make your app available to users outside of the U.S. and Canada because this means you are exporting an app using encryption from the App Store servers located in the U.S.

You do need to [submit a self classification report](https://getonthestore.com/export-compliance/) between January 1st and February 1st.